# How can I used dashed or dotted line for drawbox in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How can I used dashed or dotted line (instead of the default solid line) for drawbox in ffmpeg? In general, is there anyway I can customize the look of objects drawn?

I don't find anything that allows me to do that in the documentation.

Comment: Not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is not implemented by ffmpeg